# Azure Linux container running react app fails to start

Tags: reactjs, azure, powershell, azure-container-instances

While starting a react app on azure Linux container following error is thrown. The image runs successfully on docker container in local machine.

[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Project is running at http://192.168.0.13/
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: webpack output is served from
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Content not from webpack is served from /react-assignment1/public
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

node:events:491
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: spawn /mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe ENOENT
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn /mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe',
path: '/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe',
spawnargs: [
'-NoProfile',
'-NonInteractive',
'–ExecutionPolicy',
'Bypass',
'-EncodedCommand',
'UwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAIgBoAHQAdABwADoALwAvAGwAbwBjAGEAbABoAG8AcwB0ADoAMwAwADAAMAAiAA=='
]
}

Node.js v18.14.1

Comment: let's see your dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

**I have tried reproducing the same using the steps below and got positive results.**

**Step 1:** Create react app using the below command.

```
#npx create-react-app <app-name>
```

Refer to this link [Create a New React App – React (reactjs.org)](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) for more information on creating react app.

**Step 2:** Write Dockerfile and place it in the root folder of the react application.

```
FROM node:18-alpine3.16
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
CMD ["npx", "serve", "-s", "build"]
```

[image]

**Step 3:** Build the Dockerfile with the below command and verify the docker image.

```
 $docker build -t <image_name> <location of the docker file> (“.” Indicates current working directory) 
 `$docker image`s --> to check for images
```

[image]

**Step 4:** Run the image locally using the below command and access it on the browser.

```
$docker run -d -p <host port>:<container port> <image name>
```

[image]

[image]

**Step 5:** Tag the docker image with the ACR login server name and push it to ACR.

```
$docker tag reactappaci10:latest humbleacr.azurecr.io/reactappaci10:latest
$docker images
$docker push humbleacr.azurecr.io/reactappaci10
```

[image]
[image]

**Step 6:** Create Azure Container Instance with the below configuration.

[image]

***Note: ACI port and container port must be the same.***

[image]

Now access the **[ip address:port]** in the browser.

[image]